# How Can I show This blue Marked Border in The Form View?

Tags: ms-access

Hello Guys I'am using Ms access 2013 And I Searched Alot For Forms Proprieties To show this Blue Marked border 
Any Help , [Form Border Outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2TRD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in Windows 10 using Access 2016. It is up to the OS.

See, for example, the screenshot of a *messagebox* and an *inputbox* in my article here:

[Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013+](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17684/Modern-Metro-style-message-box-and-input-box-for-Microsoft-Access-2013.html)

which was created under Windows 8.1 with Access 2013. In Windows 10, the thick borders will be gone - or rather: they have become thin and totally transparent.

Comment: I approach you answer Iam using windows 8 and ms version 2013 so I must change my operating system 